# How to turn the first n bits of a digest into a integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, digest

I'm workign with Python 3, trying get an integer out of a digest in python. I'm only interested in the first n bits of the digest though.

What I have right now is this:

```
n = 3
int(hashlib.sha1(b'test').digest()[0:n])
```

This however results in a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xa9J'` error.

Thanks.

Comment: Bits or bytes? A slice of the digest will be measured in bytes, not bits; you were pulling `n` bytes there.

Comment: I was hoping to get the first n bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Py3 solution is to use [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) to convert `bytes` to `int`, then shift off the part you don't care about:

```
def bitsof(bt, nbits):
    # Directly convert enough bytes to an int to ensure you have at least as many bits
    # as needed, but no more
    neededbytes = (nbits+7)//8
    if neededbytes > len(bt):
        raise ValueError("Require {} bytes, received {}".format(neededbytes, len(bt))) 
    i = int.from_bytes(bt[:neededbytes], 'big')
    # If there were a non-byte aligned number of bits requested,
    # shift off the excess from the right (which came from the last byte processed)
    if nbits % 8:
        i >>= 8 - nbits % 8
    return i
```

Example use:

```
>>> bitsof(hashlib.sha1(b'test').digest(), 3)
5  # The leftmost bits of the a nibble that begins the hash
```

On Python 2, the function can be used almost as is, aside from adding a `binascii` import, and changing the conversion from `bytes` to `int` to the slightly less efficient two step conversion (from `str` to hex representation, then using `int` with `base` of 16 to parse it):

```
    i = int(binascii.hexlify(bt[:neededbytes]), 16)
```

Everything else works as is (even the `//` operator works as expected; Python 2's `/` operator is different from Py 3's, but `//` works the same on both).